# After plugin activation hook

Tags: plugin-development, hooks

Does it **OK**, to send email (to me) after user activate my plugin?

Does it a right way to do that (https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/activation-deactivation-hooks/) with hook?

thanks

Comment: Depends what you mean by 'OK'? Possible—yes. A good idea—probably not.

Comment: OK - means terms and conditions =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of official plugin repository this is very explicitly forbidden by the guidelines (emphasis mine):

> 7. No "phoning home" without user's informed consent. This seemingly simple rule actually covers several different aspects:
>
> - No unauthorized collection of user data. **For example, sending the admin's email address back to your own servers without permission of the user is not allowed**; but asking the user for an email address and collecting if they choose to submit it is fine.
>
> https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/guidelines/

Other than that it will risk you reputation (imagine what user will really *like* discovering you did it?) and might have legal implications.

Comment: Thank you so much, that what I am looking for. So I will ask the user's permission to do so.